# Calculating the EMF induced due to EM radiation

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, radiation, plasma-physics, ionization-energy

For some context, I'm trying to test if a given medium will break down upon passing radiation through it. In particular, the phenomenon I am referring to is the creation of an electric potential due to EM radiation.

Is there a way that I can calculate the electric field induced by any form of EM radiation? If so, could you please state and explain the formula?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this website https://courses.lumenlearning.com/physics/chapter/24-4-energy-in-electromagnetic-waves/

The intensity of the EM wave (in watts/m^2) is given by

[image]

Notice it depends on the electric field squared, and the permeability of the medium. Therefore if you know the intensity of the radiation and the permeability of the medium it is passing through you will be able to calculate the electric field.

I always have to check, but I believe if you are looking at the time averaged intensity, then E is the RMS value of the E field. So the peak E field would be the RMS value multiplied by sqrt(2).